# Sorting bar chart values that have been grouped in descending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running into an issue where I can't get my bar chart to show up in descending order of a column grouped by region.

I have tried to order the values and then group by and plot on a bar chart.

```py
df1 = df.drop(['Total Volume', '4046', '4225', '4770', 'Total Bags', 'Small Bags', 'Large Bags', 'XLarge Bags', 'year', 'Unnamed: 0', 'Date'], axis=1)
df1 = df1.sort_values(['AveragePrice'],ascending=True).groupby('region').mean().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))
```

The graph still plots the values out in alphabetical order by region.
[image]

Comment: Please include the dataframe you're using in your post (not as an image) so others can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: have you tried to perform the **groupby** before you perform the **sort_values**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the values first then sort and change `ascending=True` to `False`:

```
df1 = df1.groupby('region').mean().sort_values(['AveragePrice'],ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))
```

Also, that code will overwrite `df1` as a Matplotlib subplot instead of updating the dataframe. Further calls to `df1` will just output the type (`matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`) instead of displaying the dataframe.

To update `df1` with the grouped and sorted dataframe you should first manipulate the dataframe and save it, then call plot on the updated dataframe, as shown below:

```
# Manipulate the dataframe
df1 = df1.groupby('region').mean().sort_values(['AveragePrice'],ascending=False)

# Plot the results
df1.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))
```

This way, further calls to `df1` will display the grouped and sorted dataframe as expected.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I needed. I am brand new to Python so I appreciate the detail behind your answer.